# The resource from [...] was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff) with pug and express

Tags: html, node.js, express, frontend, pug

i'm trying to charge a style.css in an pug and express project.
I tried lot of tricks found in the other topics but noting works.

here the app.js file:

```
const app = express();
const pug = require('pug');
const path = require('path')
const helmet = require('helmet')

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
        defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
        scriptSrc: ["'self'"],
        styleSrc: ["'self'"]
    }
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/views')));


console.log(app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/views'))))

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('index');
})

app.listen(8080);
```

here the index.pug file:

```
    head
        meta(http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://localhost:8080")
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="/views/css/style.css")
    body
        h1='hello world'
```

I already tried to delete the rel attribute of the link tag and others basics stuff.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works for me:

```
router.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
```

Get the resource with:

```
link(rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css")
```

If you want or need the word `views` in your url then this combination should work:

```
router.use('/views', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));

link(rel="stylesheet" href="/views/css/style.css")
```